Transition can not get to work when using Tailwind
I've following code and I'm trying to get the transition to work, but could not. Seems something is wrong and I could not figure it out.
<div id="nav-links" class="fixed bg-bg-white overflow-scroll h-screen min-w-[80vw] left-[-100%] top-0 p-3 z-40 hidden transition-all duration-1000 ease-in">
</div>


 <div class="flex flex-col gap-1 cursor-pointer" onclick="navOpen()">
    <div class="w-7 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-1 bg-black dounded-md"></div>
    <div class="w-6 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
</div>

Below is the JS.
function navOpen() {
    
    const Overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    const NavLinks = document.getElementById('nav-links');

    document.body.classList.add('h-screen', 'overflow-hidden');
    Overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
    NavLinks.classList.remove('hidden', 'left-[100%]');
    NavLinks.classList.add('left-0');
}


CSS transitions cannot happen on the same frame the display is changed from none. You can wait a frame using requestAnimationFrame() and adjusting the left property for the new frame:


function navOpen() {
  // const Overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  const NavLinks = document.getElementById('nav-links');

  document.body.classList.add('h-screen', 'overflow-hidden');
  // Overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  NavLinks.classList.remove('hidden');
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    NavLinks.classList.remove('left-[-100%]');
    NavLinks.classList.add('left-0');
  });
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="nav-links" class="fixed bg-bg-white overflow-scroll h-screen min-w-[80vw] left-[-100%] top-0 p-3 z-40 hidden transition-all duration-1000 ease-in">
</div>

<div class="flex flex-col gap-1 cursor-pointer" onclick="navOpen()">
  <div class="w-7 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
  <div class="w-8 h-1 bg-black dounded-md"></div>
  <div class="w-6 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
</div>



You may also wish to consider transitioning with transform: translateX() since it is more performant:


function navOpen() {
  // const Overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  const NavLinks = document.getElementById('nav-links');

  document.body.classList.add('h-screen', 'overflow-hidden');
  // Overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  NavLinks.classList.remove('hidden');
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    NavLinks.classList.remove('-translate-x-full');
  });
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="nav-links" class="fixed bg-bg-white overflow-scroll h-screen min-w-[80vw] -translate-x-full top-0 p-3 z-40 hidden transition duration-1000 ease-in">
</div>

<div class="flex flex-col gap-1 cursor-pointer" onclick="navOpen()">
  <div class="w-7 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
  <div class="w-8 h-1 bg-black dounded-md"></div>
  <div class="w-6 h-1 bg-black rounded-md"></div>
</div>




Great explanation. In this case also what I notice is I don't need to use the hidden at all. When only using the -translate-x-full don't need to use requestAnimationFrame().
